# Using custom commands in preamble

Tags: macros, preamble

I have a the following command in a resume.cls file

```
\newcommand{\name}[1][]{\newcommand{\@name}{#1}}
```

I try to use it in my tex file with

```
\documentclass{resume}
\name{My Name}
% use \@name in fancyhdr
\begin{document}
% body
\end{document}
```

But I get

```
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}

l.5 \name{M
            y Name}
```

Can you not issue custom commands in the preamble?

Comment: Where is this class file coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\name}[1][]{\newcommand{\@name}{#1}}
```

defines `\name` to have an optional argument so the syntax for use is

```
\name[My Name]
```

with square brackets.